# Upgrading to latest Wakanda Enterprise: decipher error codes?

Tags: wakanda

I am trying to move to the latest version of Wakanda Enterprise and my solution, originally created in V10 enterprise, won't even launch. Below are the error codes. I searched for some kind of index to look up the codes but I could not find one.

`2016-09-28 13:50:33 [wakanda.PlannerTool2.PlannerTool2.xbox] ERROR - [614] "{newname}" is an invalid name for file {path}., task #1299
2016-09-28 13:50:33 [wakanda.PlannerTool2.PlannerTool2.iasv] ERROR - [1054] Cannot post 'applicationWillStart' message to services, task #1299
2016-09-28 13:50:33 [wakanda.PlannerTool2.PlannerTool2.xbox] ERROR - [650] Directory not found (dirNFErr)., task #1299`

I tried this on 2 different machines (both Mac) and am an admin on one of them-- both had the same error codes.

I am trying to upgrade to 11.197492 and the same exact errors happen when I try to launch using 11.196912

My .waProject file:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

`<project>`

```
`<folder path="./Widgets/">`
    `<tag name="widgets"/>`
`</folder>`
`<folder path="./Themes/">`
    `<tag name="themes"/>`
`</folder>`
`<file path="./Model.waModel">`
    `<tag name="catalog"/>`
`</file>`
`<file path="./Settings.waSettings">`
    `<tag name="settings"/>`
`</file>`
`<file path="./Permissions.waPerm">`
    `<tag name="permissions"/>`
`</file>`
`<file path="./bootstrap.js">`
    `<tag name="bootStrap"/>`
`</file>`
```

`</project>`

Comment: I would guess that one of your service is not working properly. What is the {newname} variable corresponding to ? Something in a service module ?

Comment: - what is the path of your service ? `/PROJECT/Modules/service.js ? (M or m for module ?)
- is your filesystem case sensitive ?
- what is the content of your `waProject` file

Comment: I added my waProject file contents to the original post. I checked all the relative paths to each file and they all exist where the waProject file points to. Also, I have not coded any angular bindings or anything like "{newname}" so this is definitely code from the Wakanda Server application itself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply by the way. I do have a case-sensitive filesystem (Mac OS X). I also do not have a service.js - I haven't registered the Wakanda Server as a service either.